# What are the default precision and scale for floating point types in EF core 6?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am receiving the following warning:

> No store type was specified for the decimal property 'PurchasePrice' on entity type 'ProductStatisticsKeylessEntity'. **This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale.** Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'.

(emphasis mine)

I know how to set a precision and scale, but I want to know the EF default values - what exactly are the default precision and scale for `decimal`, `float` or `double`?

Perhaps the default values are good enough and i can set the precision/scale to the same values to hide the errors.

Comment: Pretty suprised this info is so hard to come by..

Comment: Putting this as a comment rather than an answer, because I am not 100% certain of this, but I believe the default mappings are in the hands of the DB provider. So, for example, Oracle's default mapping may be different from SQL Server's.

Comment: Note that this is only relevant for decimal that, contrary to float and double, has a fixed separation between the integral and fraction parts. There's not such a thing as Double(18,2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any official documentation on default precision and scale mappings of C# `decimal` to SQL Server `decimal`. The quickest way is just to try.

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerTypeMappingSource.cs) (see the initialization of the `_clrTypeMappings` field) reveals that decimals are mapped by default to `decimal(18,2)`, as they have always been in Entity Framework.

Both `float` and `double` only have precision (and exponent, but no scale), so the question doesn't really apply here. But for these types it matters to which SQL Serer types they are mapped, because the definitions on both sides differ confusingly.

If we let EF generate a table from this class...

```cs
public class Num
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Dec { get; set; }
    public float Float { get; set; }
    public double Double { get; set; }
}
```

... we get this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nums](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Dec] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Float] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Double] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Nums] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]))
```

So the default mappings from CLR to SQL Server types are:

- `decimal` to `decimal(18,2)`
- `float` to `real`
- `double` to `float`

Note that for `float` (CLR) this isn't really a default, it is the only mapping that makes sense. For `double` it is a default because the precision of `double` can be cut down by mapping instructions like:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Num>().Property(e => e.Double).HasPrecision(24);
}
```

In this case the `Double` property will mapped to a `real` in SQL Server because it has the [storage size of a real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Welp i think `SqlServerTypeMappingSource` saids it all. Thanks for your little investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look, here are new changes in .NET 6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt

> The Data Annotation for configuring precision and scale was introduced in EF Core 6.0.

You can set like this:

```
[Precision(14, 2)]
public decimal Score { get; set; }
```